# Inheritance in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql

I am doing OO-SQL in DB2 environment. I have a schema as Person(URL, name) which has two subtypes Editor(noOfJournals) and Attendees(noOfConferences). In my design, one person can be both and Editor and an Attendee, but I want to physically store it only once in the database to prevent redundancy. Put another way, if Joe is both an Editor and Attendee, exactly how and into what table do I insert its tuple?

Thanks.

Sayyid

Answer (score 1):

You'd insert 'Joe' in both the Editor and Attendees tables.

*Redundant* doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. Loosely speaking, *redundant* means "the same value with the same meaning".

The value "Joe" doesn't mean the same thing when it appears in the Editor table as it does when it appears in the Attendees table. In one table, it means that Joe is an editor. In the other table, it means that Joe is attending a conference.